# How can I exactly use normals? Are they even useful in the first place?

Tags: texturing

I tried to bake some pants, but they look like that... is that normal?

Also, is there a [explain like I'm five](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ELI5#Phrase) guide on how to use Blender textures like normals and ambient occlusions, like what I'm I supposed to do with them and how I should use them the final and epic day where I will make one that actually works?

[image]

It seems it worked, thanks.

[image]

Comment: it looks like there are small details that don't show up on your normal map, maybe share your file so that we can test a bake? As for your second question, it is much too broad, please be more specific

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/9e7c4ad24bff40f5a216849568d659ed

Comment: You are trying to bake from multires, I've also failed to make it work, I don't know why, so  maybe apply it and use Selected to Active?

Comment: If one of the answers solved your problem then upvoting and marking it as accepted is enough, there's no need to edit the question with "solved, thanks".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there might be some issues with your workflow, I have baked the normals from multires and this is my result:

[image: Normal map baking]

To achieve this I redid some of the UV-maps to reduce stretching:

[image: UV]

and then bake from multires, on the 'low poly' mesh with the multires modifier set to 0:

[image: Multires normal map baking]

One good thing of using the multires modifier is that you can bake directly on the same object without the need to use cages.  For baking with high res, low res and cages you need all 3 objects to be on the same place, and the high, low poly to intersect each other.

Please note that the normal map image texture is 2k with no alpha channel (not needed) and 32-bit floating point for maximum precision.

Comment: i tried using the ''bake from multiresulotuion'' before and it just baked everything white, will try again by adding those nodes

Comment: those nodes (shader nodes?) are for rendering, not for baking, for baking you only need to add the Image Texture -> new, uncheck alpha (not used for normals) and check 32 bit floats, ensure that the image texture is selected before baking.

For baking you only have to check the bake from multiresolution, and lower the resolution of the multires modifier (i left it as it was) of the mesh.

Comment: Judging from the screenshots in the question you are both using very different blender versions, maybe this is why you don't have the same result ?

Comment: No, I don't think so.  The baking process is the same https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/render/blender_render/bake.html

However, he is using a very old, 2.79 version, i'm using the lastest stable (3.0).  You can download it from Steam and it will keep it updated.  Totally recommended that you upgrade to latest or LTS (long term support). 2.7 is very, very old.